# Regex expression for masking SSN in java 8

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

String input = "456-67-8901";

String pattern = "^\\d{3}[- ]?\\d{2}[- ]?\\d{4}$";
String result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "XXX-XX-$1");
```

showing error at Regex.Replace (Regex cannot be resolved). Am using java 8. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: So where did the identifier `Regex` come from?  That came clean out of the ether as far as I'm concerned, too.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49844334/edit) your question to include a [mcve], emphasis on **complete** - there's relevant code that's not included in your post (we can't tell if you've declared `Regex` or not).

Comment: Seems you are trying to call C# library in Java.

Comment: Sorry for that, am new to stack overflow. next i will be taking care of these things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this, to put XXX-XX- in place of the first five digits. I modified your regex a bit with two capture groups such that the first five numbers would be returned by `m.group(1)`. You're interested in `m.group(2)` though. See below:

```
    String input = "456-67-8901";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(\\d{3}[- ]?\\d{2}[- ]?)(\\d{4})$");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.println("XXX-XX-" + m.group(2));
    } else {
        // bad input
    }
```

Comment: thank u william , it worked.

Comment: the same code how can we write in spark +java. Can you please help me.

Comment: @deepthi unfortunately I'm not familliar with spark.

Comment: oh, that's fine, no problem